# Oracle DB SQL Procedure Iterate over table with dynamic table bame

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I'm working on an Oracle Stored procedure.
I need to iterate over rows of a table . I can do that using:

```
FOR eachrow IN table_name
LOOP
END LOOP;
```

But i need the table_name to be dynamic.
For example the table names are stored in some other table.
So, i can do FOR loop on that table and inside the loop ,i want to iterate through the rows of the new table.

Please suggest how i can achieve that.

Thanks,
Sash

Comment: and what do you want to do in the `for loop`? There must be something in common with the selected rows (columns)?

Comment: @Frank I need the data from each of those tables

Comment: Did you know that you (almost) never need to use a cursor on data because you can rewrite that row-by-row-logic using plain SQL?

Comment: @dnoeth This loop is actually a part of a big sql procedure that i'm trying to write. I will update the question to help you understand question better. Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible with a `FOR eachrow IN table_name LOOP`, you have to use a ref cursor instead:

First of all some sample data. These tables have some column names in common, in your inner for loop you can only access these columns, this is what I wrote in my comment above. Result type should be the same in the inner loop.

```
create table froc_a(id number, name varchar2(10), row_added date);
insert into froc_a values (1, '1', sysdate);
insert into froc_a values (2, '2', sysdate - 2);
insert into froc_a values (4, '4', sysdate - 4);

create table froc_b(id number, name2 varchar2(10), row_added date);
insert into froc_b values (1, 'b1', sysdate);
insert into froc_b values (2, 'b2', sysdate - 2);
insert into froc_b values (4, 'b4', sysdate - 4);

create table froc_c(id number, txt varchar2(10), row_added date);
insert into froc_c values (1, 'c1', sysdate);
insert into froc_c values (2, 'c2', sysdate - 2);
insert into froc_c values (4, 'c4', sysdate - 4);
```

Here is a first approach how to write it:

```
declare
  TYPE curtype IS REF CURSOR;
  l_cursor   curtype;
  l_param_id number;
  l_id       number;
  l_val      varchar2(100);
begin
  l_param_id := 1;

  -- Loop over your table names
  for l_rec in (with tabnames(name) as
                   (select 'froc_a'
                     from dual
                   union all
                   select 'froc_b'
                     from dual
                   union all
                   select 'froc_c'
                     from dual)
                  select * from tabnames) loop
    dbms_output.put_line(l_rec.name);

    -- Open cursor for current table 
    open l_cursor for 'select id, row_added from ' || l_rec.name || ' where id = :1'
      using l_param_id;

    -- Loop over rows of current table
    loop
      fetch l_cursor
        into l_id, l_val;
      exit when l_cursor%notfound;
      dbms_output.put_line(l_id || ', ' || l_val);
    end loop;
  end loop;
end;
```

Output:

```
froc_a
1, 06-APR-16
froc_b
1, 06-APR-16
froc_c
1, 06-APR-16
```